What's going on in the sky?
Feyd-Rautha enters the gladiator arena, and the camera pans up to the
sky to reveal a dramatic spectacle:

What's going on in the sky?

As I understand it, fireworks are common across all cultures as a sign of celebration. What explanations did you encounter in your researches and why did you discount the obvious?

I’m voting to close this question because "What are fireworks" is not a question about science fiction or fantasy.

@DanielRoseman They don't look like any fireworks I've seen.  Based on the the clip in the question, my first thought was rain on a dusty window.

But OP is watching the film, where it is made clear that Giedi Prime is under a "black sun" and so [handwave]therefore there are no colours[/handwave]. It would be an acceptable question to ask "why are there no colours", but this question really is just "what are fireworks".

I think OP here may be risking an automatic question ban. If two of these mass produced Dune questions didn't got to HNQ, it might happened already.

Without knowing the universe of Dune but just having a basic grasp of the universe, I thought those were explosions caused by outer space missiles blowing on a force field. Close enough, I guess.

What you are seeing is a fireworks display. Giedi Prime, the homeworld of the Harkonnens, is under a black sun, so the display looks different from what you would see on Earth. The look was achieved by shooting the scene with infrared cameras, giving the fireworks an otherworldly appearance. According to Dune cinematographer Greig Fraser:

For years, I’ve been experimenting with using infrared light to film things. This goes back to the days of Zero Dark Thirty, where I used infrared to light some of the raid scenes, but that was a night vision camera, not an infrared camera. I started experimenting with what infrared light could do. [...] That’s the ghoulish look that comes from cameras at night, and I’ve always loved that look. So when Denis and I talked about the light in Giedi Prime being different and colorless, I told him that I thought I had the right technique for this, and I presented it to him, and he loved it. It’s otherworldly, yet we recognize it, but we’re not sure why.

Inspired by director Denis Villenueve's notion that Feyd-Rautha should be celebrated with "anti-fireworks," Fraser looked to multiple real-life influences:

We’re very fortunate technologically that we can run video through lights. So I was running video through those lights of arc welders, inverted fireworks, and jellyfish. That was an idea Patrice had, to run some video of jellyfish, and while you don’t see them on the screen, the fireworks are inspired by these video files running through the lights.

Source: Motion Picture Association Interview with Dune Cinematographer Greig Fraser

Why would you answer this guys terrible questions? Do you really need the extra rep so much?  Don't encourage him.

@JK. To be fair, not everyone knows the context of what this user has been doing. In any case, I see he's been automatically banned for a few days now. I hope he learns his lesson and makes an effort to start asking real questions.

It was a little mod ban, automatic question bans are nasty. 6 months and even then there's no guarantee. Can be lifted with fixing/reopening/undeleting old questions, though.
